# I cant get PHPUnit to work within NetBeans (Mac)

Tags: macos, netbeans, phpunit

My NetBeans have an option to add a path to a script that runs PHPUnit, however when I try to add this script to my NetBeans I get the error that it doesn't recognize the version. Says that version is ?.?.? and that is not supported. However my PHPUnit version is supported by NetBeans and work perfectly when I run it from the pear installer folder (PHP).

"Selected PHPUnit (version ?.?.?) is too old, upgrade it if possible (the minimum version is 3.3.0)" - I got 3.6.4.

My script looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh
phpunit --bootstrap MyBootstrap.php --stderr $*
```

And it works great on linux NetBeans. Just not on my Mac.
And yes it works perfect when I run it in the console.

Thanks a milion

/Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue about version soved by reinstalling everything, however I now get this

PHPUnit 3.6.7 by Sebastian Bergmann.

The Xdebug extension is not loaded. No code coverage will be generated.

Cannot open file "/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans".

How could I load Xdebug? Is that in php.ini or apache conf? or is that in NetBeans?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what php runner is, but to recognize valid PhpUnit, NetBeans run command "phpunit --version", so check what this command gives you in console.

Once I had problem with this, so I simply found the code of phpunit that is responsible for "phpunit --version" and manually type what should be printed when this command is executed. So NetBeans "saw" correct version and everybody is happy :)

Comment: if I run in the console: ./phpunit.sh --version - I get: PHPUnit 3.6.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Comment: So you have to go to the phpunit directory and run "./phpunit.sh"? That could be the problem, you have to be able to run the command "phpunit --version" (not with "./" or "...sh") anywhere, so it have to be on your $PATH (I'm not sure how it works on Mac)

Comment: well, I can run phpunit --version from anywhere and I can this .sh file is located in my project folder, which I try to link my NetBeans to. It is quite strange, I can run all tests perfectly through commandline, only reason I want it in NetBeans is due to the coverage view.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the phpunit problem (too old phpunit message on netbeans)

First open terminal and then:

- `cd /private/etc`
- `cp php.ini.default php.ini`
- open `php.ini` file
- change `include_path` to `include_path = ".:/usr/share/pear"`

Problem solved :)

If however the problem is not solved then try install `netbeans` for php from [netbeans.org](http://netbeans.org)

Answer (score 1):

Mate, that is error by Netbeans (see [bug id 188240](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=188240)), and it looks like it is not fixed yet. It happens on Mac OSX.

What i did is to rename `Application/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.1.1` to `Application/NetBeans/NetBeans7.1.1` (note the lack of space)

as per Xdebug, read this:
http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php

when you get the version for your server, add these lines into your php.ini:

```
zend_extension = /opt/local/lib/php/extensions/<name of your extension>/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

replacing `<name of your extension>` with, of course, the name of your extension :)

after this you should be ready to go.

Comment: Are you sure that this issue has yet to be resolved? The last comment in that bug does appear to be a note about a fix having been committed.

Comment: @WillPalmer: Status: RESOLVED INCOMPLETE - so I won't give that last comment so much attention.